# create an element on the last of lists

Tags: jquery

I've got a list and I'm trying to create an element when you click on one of the last row. I'm not sure how to explain it, so here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckgL3zxd/4/

As you can see the element with the `class="blue"` will be created between the lists, but not when you click on the last row. This is because there is no `li` that matches the JQuery `eq()`.

Does someone know how to fix this?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
.active {
    background: red;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    var lisInRow = 0;

    $('ul li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
            lisInRow++;
        } else {
            lisInRow++;
        }
    });


    var calc = ($(this).index() + 1) / lisInRow,
        roundup = Math.ceil(calc),
        together = roundup * lisInRow;

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('ul li').removeClass('active').siblings('.blue').remove();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('ul li').eq(together - 1).after('<li class="blue"></li>');
    } else {
        $('ul li').removeClass('active').siblings('.blue').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because 'together' is 18 for the last row, and you're trying to add the blue element after the 17th 'ul li', which doesn't exist. Just check if it's more than the total count of your 'ul li' objects, and if so - change it to that value.

**EDIT:** This worked for me:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    var lisInRow = 0;
    var ulLisCnt = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
    $('ul li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
            lisInRow++;
        } else {
            lisInRow++;
        }
    });


    var calc = ($(this).index() + 1) / lisInRow,
        roundup = Math.ceil(calc),
        together = roundup * lisInRow;

    if (together > ulLisCnt) together = 14;

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('ul li').removeClass('active').siblings('.blue').remove();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('ul li').eq(together - 1).after('<li class="blue"></li>');
    } else {
        $('ul li').removeClass('active').siblings('.blue').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I know, that's why I said that it doesn't match the `eq()` and that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't working for me. The blue element does go to the last of the list but then the blue element doesn't go in between the list anymore.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "in between the lists"? In your original code, clicking 1..6 creates the blue element between the first line and the second line. Clicking on elements 7..12 creates the blue element between the second line and the third line. Clicking on 13/14 did nothing due to the bug. After my change, the blue element appears after the third line. Do you expect something else?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ckgL3zxd/5/ The blue does not go in between. I'm trying exactly as you have said but your code does not do that

Comment: I counted the items incorrectly earlier. My latest edit works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eldad Mor, I have found a clue how to fix it. If the `eq()` is larger than the amount of `li`'s, create the element after the last `li`.

```
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    var lisInRow = 0;

    $('ul li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prev().length > 0) {
            if ($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
            lisInRow++;
        } else {
            lisInRow++;
        }
    });

    var calc = ($(this).index() + 1) / lisInRow,
        roundup = Math.ceil(calc),
        together = roundup * lisInRow,
        liCnt = $('ul li').length;

    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('ul li').removeClass('active').siblings('.blue').remove();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('ul li').eq(together - 1).after('<div class="blue"></div>');

        if (together > liCnt){
            $('ul li').last().after('<div class="blue"></div>');
        }
    } else {
        $('ul li').removeClass('active').siblings('.blue').remove();
    }
});
```